# Is this a valid SQL relation?

Tags: sql, database-design

I've a relation where two tables depend on each other. The **users** belong to a shop and one of those users is the **shop** boss. Since I can't do this relation without alter table it feels like this is not a good relation.

[image: Relation Image]

Comment: It's certainly going to make inserting data problematic as you'll have a key violation whichever order you do it in.

Comment: The main issue would probably come when inserting data, due to the circular reference. I also metters whether your keys are nullable. Here's a nice discussion on the topic: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/102977/192306

Comment: @SimonN: you can always use a deferred constraint to workaround that problem (at least in some DBMS products)

Comment: @MarianoLuisVilla without making the keys nullable

Comment: @somerandomdrunkcoder Then a deferred constraint would be the way to go. There are ways to work that around even if the DBMS you're using doesn't support them. But isn't it posible for a user to be the boss of more than one shop? And even for a shop to eventually have two people in charge? 'Cause you might be better off changing the relation to a 1-N or N-N.

Answer (score 0):

As I see, inserting a new row in Shop is impossible if table Users is empty (due to Boss is a fk? from the tablet User). Insert a new User is also impossible because of the same thing, so its a circular relation.

Comment: That's not a problem.  Defer the constraint.

Comment: It's not impossible is the field are nullable

Comment: Okey, that's possible but I dont think it's a good approach. I think a new column defining the role (in User table) and another table with all the possible roles would be a better way.